# How to properly pass optional refs to a child component in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to have a custom component whose visibility is linked to a ref (the default binding):

```
// TestComponent.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { toRef } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  modalValue: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  }
})

const emit = defineEmits<{'update:modelValue': [value: boolean]}>()

const isVisible = toRef(props, 'modelValue')
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="isVisible">
    <button @click="isVisible.value = false">Test</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

When calling the Component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import TestComponent from '@/components/TestComponent.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const test = ref(true)
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    {{ test }}
    <TestComponent v-bind="test" />
    <TestComponent />
  </main>
</template>
```

My problem is that while trying everything (from two-way-binding via `computed`) something doesn't work. Either the ref isn't synced back to the parent or the component without a ref binded to it doesn't disappear after clicking on the button.

Is there a reliable and best-practice-way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying and correcting for mistakes, the **TestComponent.vue** should be like this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  isVisible: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  }
})

defineEmits<{'update:isVisible': [value: boolean]}>()
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="isVisible">
    <button @click="$emit('update:isVisible', false)">Test</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

You defined an emit, but never used it, so the value was never being sent back up to the parent. I put the emit on the button click, emitting the value of false.  You had a typo with the prop name `modalValue`, it should've been `modelValue`, but since it looked like you wanted to use a name of `isVisible` I just changed it to that instead and got rid of the ref.

**Parent component**:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import TestComponent from '@/components/TestComponent.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const test = ref(true)
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    {{ test }}
    <TestComponent v-model:isVisible="test" />
  </main>
</template>
```

Here you needed to use v-model instead of v-bind. v-bind is for one-way binding, v-model is two-way.  To set the two-way binding where the child prop is called `isVisible`, the v-model should be written as `v-model:isVisible`.

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

---

#### Edit: Using v-bind

I now understand that the specific use case in the question is for an optional prop, so that the parent component and child component can both independently set the `isVisible` value.

The strategy for this is to use a local variable and a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html). If the parent changes the prop value, the watcher activates and changes the local variable. If no prop is provided, the child component can still update the local variable on it's own.

**Parent component**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import TestComponent from './TestComponent.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const test = ref(true)
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <TestComponent :isVisible="test" />
    <TestComponent />
  </main>
</template>
```

**Child component**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  isVisible: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    required: false
  }
})

const isActuallyVisible = ref(true)

watch(
  () => props.isVisible,
  (newValue) => {
    isActuallyVisible.value = newValue
  }
)
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="isActuallyVisible">
    <button @click="isActuallyVisible = false">Test</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

[updated Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thank you really much for your help! Sorry, there were some typos on my part. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, if isVisible is not provided. You can observe that, if you add another `<TestComponent />` without parameters below. I want to be sure that the isVisible is an optional addon or even can be a boolean (instead of a Ref<boolean>). Is that in any way possible?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I didn't understand what you were going for in the original question.  I've updated my answer that should hopefully help.  To address your last point, you will need to use a ref boolean in any case.  Only changes to reactive variables can cause components to rerender on the screen.  If you just used a plain boolean, the value would update but the UI would not.

Comment: No, I'm sorry that I didn't clarify enough what my goal is. :-) Simple thing still: It doesn't sync back IF a ref was provided. If you add a `{{ test }}` in the main-tag of the parent, it doesn't get updated. If I would add another watch for the `isActuallyVisible` that syncs the value back to `isVisible`, would that create an infinite loop?

Comment: The problem is solved: Two-way-databinding is possible with `v-model` instead of `v-bind`. On change you have to emit an `update`-event to sync it back.